# How will I get the last modified date of a file in a SharePoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to seek help regarding on getting the last modified date of a file in a Sharepoint. What VBA code/command will I use in order to execute it.
I would like to show this "Last Modified Date" of the file in a MsgBox when a command button is clicked.

Your prompt response is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I stumbled upon something in another line of inquiry that led me to a solution.

In your VBA window, go to Tools -> References, and then scroll down and check the box next to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Then when you specify your link it's going to read like this:

`FileDateTime("//site.com/page/file.xlsx`").

No "http:"  Once I did that, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This one had me scratching my head for a bit too...

Make sure to add "@ssl" following the root URL e.g

FileDateTime("\\site.com@ssl\file.xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
FileDateTime ( file_path )
```

to get the date and time of when a file was created or last modified.

For more information please visit the below link..

[VBA Help](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php)

Comment: Hi,i use this command to get the last modified date of a file in a sharepoint. i place the link of my sharepoint site on the file_path. but it throws an error. can you help me with this?

Comment: Hi! @Kaustav Banerjee

This is the command i execute:

Dim ModifiedDate as Date
ModifiedDate = FileDateTime("https://site1/folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/aaaa.xlsx")

Then the error is, "Run time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument".

Please help me. thanks! :)

Comment: **bold** `Dim ModifiedDate as Date ModifiedDate = FileDateTime("site1/folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/aaaa.xlsx")`

Comment: I searched for this error and got the below reference in MSDN. Can you please validate whether it is a platform related issue or not... If not then I'll try and investigate further....   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445484(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Alternately you can also try this "Public Function gsGetLastModifiedDate(rsURL As String) As String
Dim x As Object

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set x = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0")

x.Open "HEAD", rsURL, False
x.send
gsGetLastModifiedDate = x.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")

ExitRoutine:
Set x = Nothing
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
Resume ExitRoutine
End Function"

Comment: hi. can you explain the code you have given me? where will i put the URL of my Sharepoint and the name of the file? thanks a lot!

Comment: i think the code, `Dim ModifiedDate as Date ModifiedDate = FileDateTime("site1/folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/aaaa.xlsx")` is used if the file is on your local. but what if the file is in a sharepoint or a website? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestWhen()

    SPFilePath = "http://teams.MyCompany.com/sites/PATH/PATH/Fulfillment/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
    SPFileName = "2021_MyFileName.xlsx"

    MsgBox SPFileName  & " last modified on" & SPLastModified(SPFilePath, SPFileName)

End Sub


Function SPLastModified(SPUrl As String, SPFName As String)
    Dim IE As Object

    Dim PagesHTML As String
    Dim Dadate As String
    Dim DaDateEnd As String
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(OutString, " ")
 
    Dim LastChange As Variant

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate SPUrl
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        Do While .busy: DoEvents: Loop

        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        PagesHTML = ie.document.DocumentElement.outerHTML
    End With

' Get to File
    Dadate = InStr(PagesHTML, "FileLeafRef" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & SPFName)

' Get to Modified Date
    ModifiedText = "Modified" & Chr(34) & ": "
    Dadate = Dadate + InStr(Mid(PagesHTML, Dadate), ModifiedText)

    OutString = Mid(PagesHTML, Dadate + Len(ModifiedText), 27)

    arr = Split(OutString, " ")
   
    LastChange = arr(1) & " " & arr(2)    
    LastChange = arr(0) & "/" & Mid(arr(1), 6) & "/" & Mid(arr(2), 6, 4) & " " & LastChange

    SPLastModified = LastChange

End Function
```

Comment: I rewrote this without the ie functions.  Have to remember to send that over...