# Get online hosted pdf document modified date vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, modified-date

I am somewhat new to VBA and have done hours of research to see if it is possible to get the created or last modified date of a PDF document that is hosted online.

From a thread I found the FileDateTime function could possibly work however there is no information as to how to use it.

I have found and modified code from the msdn website however it returns the following error "Invalid procedure call or argument".

The below link was also helpful. stating that using the link without the "https:" works, however it seems that it only applies to Sharepoint files and has returned an error ("File no found")

[How will I get the last modified date of a file in a SharePoint using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020560/how-will-i-get-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-a-sharepoint-using-vba)

```
Sub return_created_date()

Dim MyStamp
' Assume TESTFILE was last modified on February 12, 1993 at 4:35:47 PM.
' Assume English/U.S. locale settings.
MyStamp = FileDateTime("https://www.xxxx.com/xxxx.pdf")    ' Returns "2/12/93 4:35:47 PM"

MsgBox (MyStamp)

End Sub
```

Any help on if this is possible would be appreciated